# How can I disable cakephp security?

Tags: security, cakephp

I used

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Security->validatePost = false;
    $this->Security->csrfCheck = false;
    $this->Security->unlockedActions = array('my_action');
}
```

but it's not work and still report

```
Security Error
The requested address was not found on this server.

Request blackholed due to "auth" violation.
```

I remember that it was working normally and I can post my data but it stopped suddenly. I'm not sure what happens and try all my search result but it's not work. How can I stop Security Components in CakePHP ?

I even use

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Components->disable('Security');
}
```

Comment: Simply remove the `public $components = array('Security');` part from your controller. So simply stop implementing it in your app to be able to debug the source of your problem :)

Comment: I don't have public $components = array('Security'); in my controller, I don't attemp to do that, so strange ?

Comment: That's weird. Without that part you can't even use the component (at least, it shouldn't be possible). Can you scan your app code for "Security" occurrences? Maybe that helps?

Comment: Thank bro, I inherit the system and have to manage it but the old developer call it in another template and apply it to all controller. I fixed it

Comment: So, what I was saying was the solution or .. ? Because in that case I will post it as an "answer" so that you can mark it as the solution. So that other people with a similar problem can have a look at it. Might solve it for them as well then :)

Answer (score 0):

you could try with `SecurityComponent::validatePost` using [configuration option](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/security-component.html) is for:

here is i am just defined for particular action you can chage it as per your need.

```
if(in_array($this->action,array(“some_action”))){
$this->Security->validatePost = false;

}
```